# How to update same data in different collections in cloud firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner ios developer. I have been working on a project and using cloud firestore for storing data. The problem is, suppose:

There are two different collections, i.e.
users & reviews having documents which have a field "rating" in both of them.

Now whenever a user give ratings, i want to store the individual rating in the "reviews" collection, and an aggregate of rating for the user who has been rated in the "users" collection.

These are the two separate queries for one action by the user. How to handle this situation. Should i do individual queries and update the data ?? but what if one of the update fails, the other one would be succeeded and the data is now not logically correct. How does firebase handle this, that either both or none queries should execute.

Thanks.
p.s. i had searched for group collection queries and i didn't find how to use them, and how they work. Is there any other solution ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple documents to update whose field values must stay in sync, and their updates must complete at exactly the same time, you should use a [batch write or transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).  With these operations, all documents reference in the batch or transaction will update at the same time, and if any of the updates fail, the entire batch or transaction is rolled back.

Comment: In fact, what OP describes is exactly the topic of step 7 in the codelab here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-ios/#6